# Using strcmp on a subset of a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcmp

I want to use `strcmp` to compare the subset of a string with another string.

Say I have:

`a[] = {'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l',d'};`

and

`b[] = {'w','o','r','l','d};`

I want to compare the second word of `a` with the entire string `b`. I know the starting index of the second word in `a`. Is there a way to do this directly using `strcmp` or does more word on `a` need to be done first?

Comment: You should be using `strncmp( a+6, b, 5 )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` and `b` are `char` arrays, but they are not strings, because they are not null-terminated.

If they were modified to null-terminated like this:

```
char a[] = {'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d', '\0'};

char b[] = {'w','o','r','l','d', '\0'};
```

And the index of the second word of `a` is known like you said, then yes, you can use `strcmp(a + 6, b)` to compare.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (strcmp(&a[6],b) == 0)
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strcmp((a + index), b) == 0) { ... }
```

strcmp takes two pointers, so you add the index directly.

However, you should add a terminating NULL byte to each string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those are *actually* strings rather than character arrays with no string terminator, this is quite easy to do.

You sate you no the index of the `w` in world so it's a matter of:

```
strcmp (b, a+index)
```

or:

```
strcmp (b, &(a[index]))
```

depending on which you think reads better (the underlying code should be pretty much the same).

See, for example, this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    char *str1 = "world";
    char *str2 = "hello world";

    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen (str2); i++)
        printf ("%s on match '%s' with '%s'\n",
            strcmp (str1, str2+i) ? "No " : "Yes",
            str1, str2+i);

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
No  on match 'world' with 'hello world'
No  on match 'world' with 'ello world'
No  on match 'world' with 'llo world'
No  on match 'world' with 'lo world'
No  on match 'world' with 'o world'
No  on match 'world' with ' world'
Yes on match 'world' with 'world'
No  on match 'world' with 'orld'
No  on match 'world' with 'rld'
No  on match 'world' with 'ld'
No  on match 'world' with 'd'
```

---

Whether they're string literals or properly terminated character arrays will make no difference. Replacing the two declaration lines with:

```
char str1[] = {'w','o','r','l','d','\0'};
char str2[] = {'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d','\0'};
```

will work equally well.

If they're *not* properly terminated, the `str...` calls are not really the right ones to use.

Comment: If these were null terminated character arrays, would the same approach work?

Comment: @PythonNewb, yes, it would. Though arrays and pointers are different things, the former often decay into the latter. The way the code is using it means it makes no difference. See the update.